# Inequalities for Differences of Absolute Values of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. Let $A=USU^T$ be the eigen-decomposition $A$ and let $|A|=U|S|U^T$ where $|S|$ just denotes elementwise absolute value of the diagonal matrix $S$. $|B|$ is defined similarly.

(Sometimes it is written $|A|=(A^T A)^{1/2}$. Ie $|A|$ is the positive definite matrix with the same eigenvectors and same *singular* values as $A$).

Suppose $\|\cdot\|$ is the standard $L^{2}$ operator norm on $n\times n $ matrices, so $\|A\|=\sup_{x} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$.

Is it true that $\|A-B\| \geq \| |A|-|B|\|$?

Note, for vectors and the 2-norm where we take the absolute value element-wise, this is true since it is true of the real numbers.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's true, but a proof eludes me.  Intuitively, $A-B$ can take advantage of combining mixtures of positive eigenvalue(s) of $A$ with mixtures of negative eigenvalues(s) of $B$ (or vice-versa) to produce a large eigenvalue, whereas $|A| - |B|$ cannot because all eigenvalues of $|A|$ and $|B|$ are non-negative.  So this should be true because your norm is equal to the largest eigenvalue magnitude.

Comment: Thank you @user2566092. Yes, this is my intuition as well. If for example A and B were simultaneously diagonalizable it just reduces to the case of vector norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem correct in general. Mathematica code:

```
A = {{2, 1}, {1, 1}};
B = {{2, 2}, {2, 1}};
Print["SD(A) = ", Map[MatrixForm, SchurDecomposition[A // N]]]
Print["SD(B) = ", Map[MatrixForm, {u, t} = SchurDecomposition[B // N]]]
Print["B = ", u.t.Transpose[u] // MatrixForm]
Print["|B| = ", (B2 = u.Abs[t].Transpose[u]) // MatrixForm]
Print["SD(|B|) = ", Map[MatrixForm, SchurDecomposition[B2 // N]]]
Print["|A-B| = ", Norm[A - B, 2] // N]
Print["|A-|B|| = ", Norm[A - B2, 2]]
Print["|A-B| - |A-|B|| = ", Norm[A - B, 2] - Norm[A - B2, 2]]
```

produces this output:

```
SD(A) = {(
    0.850651    -0.525731
    0.525731    0.850651
    )
,
    (
    2.61803 0.
    0.  0.381966
    )
}
SD(B) = {(
    0.788205    -0.615412
    0.615412    0.788205
    )
,
    (
    3.56155 0.
    0.  -0.561553
    )
}
B = (
2.  2.
2.  1.
)
|B| = (
2.42536 1.45521
1.45521 1.69775
)
SD(|B|) = {(
    0.788205    -0.615412
    0.615412    0.788205
    )
,
    (
    3.56155 0.
    0.  0.561553
)}
|A-B| = 1.
|A-|B|| = 1.0367
|A-B| - |A-|B|| = -0.0367044
```

The norm is exactly the one you're saying it is, and $A = |A|$ is positive definite, so didn't need to compute $|A|$.

A simple criterion is if they commute, because in that case they are simultaneously orthonormally diagonalizable.

I don't see a clear criterion for both directions. If we set $a_{11} = 2.04309043$ in the above example, you get $\|A-B\| - \||A|-|B|\| \approx 6.15326 \cdot 10^{-9}$ and, beyond that, we get bigger positives.

Defining

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix},$$

we get the following plots for $f(x) := \|A-B\| - \||A|-|B|\|$:

[image: Plot for f(x) for x in <1,2.1>]
[image: Plot for f(x) for x in <-17,3>]

The second one was made with $|A|$ instead of $A$, since $A$ stops being positive definite.

I tried looking at the eigenvalues a bit, but I see no useful patterns.

Comment: Thank you @Vedran Šego. 
I will have to think about if there are other specific conditions I can put on the matrices so that the inequality does hold.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I didn't find much, but it may help you.

Comment: Interesting! The plots are somewhat fascinating.

I think I have found a way around using a result like this for what I am working on and I believe your answer has helped deepen my understanding of the problem!